# Count working hours with options

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql query who works fine, but i need some options or filters.
This query count all hours between the first date and end date.

```
    SELECT hour(timediff('2013-11-26 23:51:20',
                         '2013-11-28 15:51:10'))
        AS totalhour
    ----
    totalhour
    39
```

It is possible to get the SUM of a count of only the hours between 08h - 17h and only between Monday to Friday?

The schema is like that:

```
    CREATE TABLE `test` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `title` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
      `first_date` date NOT NULL,
      `last_date` date NOT NULL,
      `begin_hour` time NOT NULL,
      `end_hour` time NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;

    /*Data for the table `test` */

    insert  into `test`(`id`,`title`,`first_date`,`last_date`,`begin_hour`,`end_hour`) values 
    (1,'Test1','2013-11-26','2013-11-28','06:00:20','20:00:20'),
    (2,'Test2','2013-11-29','2013-12-03','09:00:10','15:51:10');
```

Like that
From 2013-11-29 at '09:00:10' To '2013-12-03' at'15:00:00' =  **23 h**

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can

```
   SELECT hour(timediff('2013-11-26 23:51:20',
                         '2013-11-28 15:51:10'))
        AS totalhour
  ... your remaing query

WHERE  HOUR(dat_time_col) BETWEEN '8' AND '17' AND DAYNAME(dat_time_col) 
   IN('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday')
```

`dat_time_col` this will be your date time column name and make sure you have  proper data type for this column

[**HOUR(date)**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_hour)

[**DAYNAME(date)**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayname)

<kbd>[**See fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c462de/2)</kbd>

Comment: Hi dianuj, THX for your help. I have tried your demo, but i get not a valid result. I have change the end date to 05/12/2013 and i get 15 hours, but it must be more: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/383c02/1/0)

Comment: @achillix add your fiddle with your dataset

Comment: I want the SUM of all hours between the first and the last date (both are in the same row.)

Comment: I did it :  [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/65e15/1)   and i have changed my question. I am sorry it was not good described. THX

Comment: I have tried only the first ID and i get there 40h but it must be only 17h. Do you know why?